# Automated Meta Descriptions Magento 2

Tags: magento2, meta-title, meta-description

We currently have meta data set up in the individual products. However, I would create an **automated meta description** for all products (including backdating old products).

I know I could do this through import/export - but I want something that is automated going forward.

For example, my product meta description should be '**[brand], [product-name], buy online today.**'

I can find how to do this for opengraph meta content but not meta descriptions and key words.

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: you may create product save after observer and update meta description based on above formate you mentioned. and for existing products you can create script which can load product and take brand - product name data and update meta description.

Comment: You want to show meta descriptions and key words   ` '[brand], [product-name], buy online today.`  at frontend of Magento then we can do.

Comment: That case, you don't need to update meta description  at the database level

Comment: Hi @AmitBera yes it would be on the frontend, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can use event/observer.

Fire an observer on the event  `catalog_product_load_after` at frontend area set meta description on the fly.

> Create `events.xml` at 
>   `app/code/StackExchange/Magento/etc/frontend/` and as
>   `events.xml location under on **frontend** and this event only fire
>   for frontend area.

### events.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_load_after">
        <observer instance="StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\ProductLoadAfter" 
                  name="stackexchange_magento_observer_frontend_catalog_productloadafter_catalog_product_load_after"
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Create Observer  class `ProductLoadAfter` at 
>   `app/code/StackExchange/Magento/Observer/Frontend/Catalog/`.

### ProductLoadAfter.php code

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend\Catalog;

class ProductLoadAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
     \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__);
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            $newMetaDescription = $product->getData('brand') .$product->getData('name').'-'. __('buy online today');
            $product->setMetaDescription($newMetaDescription);
           // $product->setMetaKeyword('TEST '.$newMetaDescription);
        }
    }

}
```

### Some notes:

Assume that brand is text type attribute. If the brand is an attribute of type drop attribute then you need to some extra code as `$product->getData('brand')` only give brand option id not it label mean brand name example, Puma, addidas.

### Also, your module must have:

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`
2. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
3. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.php`

**After adding the event you should  flush the cache.**

Comment: Thanks Amit. Do I need a registration.php file for this module?

Comment: yes, it need..your module must have:
`app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml.
app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json
. app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.php`

Comment: Hi Amit. Sorry about the late response on this... I tried it, and sadly, it's not having any effect on the front end. Did it work on your test site?

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera I've added code flushed cache etc. but this still doesn't produce a meta description on the front end.

Comment: Have u test the same at default Magento 2. Might some customization on your magento instance override this work

Comment: Got it working @Amit Bera  thank you. Brand is dropdown, so how do I get label rather than ID please?

Answer (score 1):

Amit's answer is correct. However, Google limits the description to 255 characters. That is why I have limited the characters of the description to 255. I have also removed any new lines and html tags, if used in the description.

```
if ($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            $newMetaDescription = $product->getData('brand').' '. $product->getData('name') .'-'. __('buy online today');
            $shortMetaDescription = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"),' ',strip_tags(substr($newMetaDescription, 0, 255)));
            $product->setMetaDescription($shortMetaDescription);
```

I have also added the 'brand' attribute to the Meta Title and put the title in the Meta Keywords. Then put a comma after each word in the keywords. So if the new title is "*New black tshirt Nike*", the Meta Keywords, would be "*new, black, tshirt, nike*". Here is the code:

```
            $pageMainTitle = $product->getData('name');
            $newMetaTitle = $pageMainTitle .$product->getData('brand');
            $product->setMetaTitle($newMetaTitle);
            $newKeywords = str_replace(' ',", ",$newMetaTitle);
            $product->setMetaKeyword($newKeywords);
```